# How to determine the end of a touch-events set?

Tags: android, touch-event

I have a small app, which uses a fullscreen activity and where I can drag an ImageView.

Now my solution works like this: I change the position of the ImageView according to the drag of the finger, so basically I'm adding the delta x (previousX - currentX) to the position of the ImageView. Now the problem is determining the previousX. It works fine for the first time, since I'm testing whether it's 0, if it's null it means the app is just started and the previous x can become the new x, however the dragging movement becomes ugly as soon as you move the finger away after dragging and start dragging again by putting the finger in a different spot than you finished dragging the first time (because it's virtually impossible to put it in the same place. So the previousX is the one from the last drag, so when you start the second drag it jumps the x difference from the previous x to the new one. I either need to change a different way of calculating this, or determine when the finger gets away from screen and the series of drag events are finished.

This is what my code for the touch event looks like:

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) img
                    .getLayoutParams();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                if (x_cord > windowWidth) {
                    x_cord = windowWidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowHeight) {
                    y_cord = windowHeight;
                }

                if (previousX == 0) {
                    previousX = x_cord;
                }
                if (previousY == 0) {
                    previousY = y_cord;
                }

                layoutParams.leftMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin
                        + (x_cord - previousX);
                layoutParams.topMargin = layoutParams.topMargin
                        + (y_cord - previousY);

                img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                previousX = x_cord;
                previousY = y_cord;

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ... ! Or even better, use the framework : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: @ElDuderino both solutions sound pretty good. About the framework, is it customizable for my case or is it more suitable to drag and drop items between different views?

Comment: @ElDuderino Well the ACTION_UP seems to be the answer to my question and the solution to my problem with my current algorithm! It moves smooth now, thank you. However I'm still wondering about the Drag and Drop framework and whether it would be possible to adapt it to my needs.

Comment: I don't know your exact case :) I have used it only to move views between other views, works like a charm, if you want to move a view freely in it's parent you might better stick to your approach...

Comment: @ElDuderino well anyway, thanks for the solutions and the suggestions that I might need in the future. You should have posted it as an answer.